# What is the ring of functions on the open unit disc with polynomially bounded Maclaurin coefficients called?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, cv.complex-variables, terminology

Let $R$ be the the set of complex-valued (analytic) functions $f$ on the open unit disc $\mathrm D:=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|<1\}$ for which there exist constants $a_0$, $a_1$, ... in $\Bbb C$ and $n$ in $\Bbb N$ such that $$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k\quad(z\in\mathrm D)\quad\text{with}\quad|a_k|<k^n$$for all sufficiently large $k$ in $\Bbb N$. This set $R$ is a ring, commutative and without zero-divisors, under the standard arithmetic operations $f+g:z\mapsto f(z)+g(z)$ and $fg:z\mapsto f(z)g(z)$. What is the usual name for this ring?

Clearly there is an exact real analogue of this, with $\mathrm D$ replaced by the open real interval $(-1\,\pmb,\,1)$. If it has a name, that would also be of interest.

(This was originally posted on Math Stack Exchange, but received no answer.)

Comment: Perhaps this is one of those many interesting phenomena without its own name?

Comment: Perhaps the best strategy is to make up your own name for this concept, and wait until someone points out that it already has a name. The *ring of power series with coefficients with polynomial growth* is descriptive, but a bit too long.